# Extract an APFS disk image without mounting it

Tags: macos, apfs, disk-image

I have disk image that is reported to have an APFS file system.

```
$ file disk.img
disk.img: Apple File System (APFS), blocksize 4096
```

How can I extract the disk image without mounting it?

Answer (score 2):

[7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) can extract disk images, but release 22.00 or later is required to to extract APFS images.

`7z` provided by the Homebrew package [p7zip](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/p7zip) currently does *not* support APFS images.

```
$ brew info p7zip | grep stable
==> p7zip: stable 17.04 (bottled)

$ /usr/local/bin/7z | grep 7-Zip
7-Zip [64] 17.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28

$ file disk.img
disk.img: Apple File System (APFS), blocksize 4096

$ /usr/local/bin/7z x disk.img 1>/dev/null
ERROR: disk.img
Can not open the file as archive
```

`7zz` provided by the Homebrew package [sevenzip](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/p7zip) does support APFS images.

```
$ brew info sevenzip | grep stable
==> sevenzip: stable 22.01 (bottled)

$ /usr/local/bin/7zz | grep 7-Zip
7-Zip (z) 22.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2022 Igor Pavlov : 2022-07-15
```

Use `7zz` to extract the disk image.

```
/usr/local/bin/7zz x disk.img
```

---

<sup>The latest binary release `7z2107-mac.tar.xz` currently offered on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip) is compiled from version 21.07 and therefore does not support APFS images.</sup>

<sup>The latest source release [`7z2201-src.tar.xz`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/22.01/7z2201-src.tar.xz/download) currently needs to be [patched](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/f41bcae0612f03d5439a9e108e1dc54758e9a352/Formula/sevenzip.rb#L26) to build.</sup>